# Can we do any changes in a flutter based, exported website? (without the base flutter code)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-html

Suppose I used flutter to build an application and then export it as a Website by using

```
flutter build web
```

Now if I give this exported web code (not flutter files) to someone, will there be any possibilities that they can do changes in logic (api calls, licensing, etc) in this code ?

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#deploying-to-the-web  ~ for reference

I tried opening the exported files, didn't understand the code though, I mean thought it would be difficult, but still want to know from experts. (PS : Am new to flutter)

Comment: Of course they can!  They can route all the traffic through a proxy that rewrites requests and responses, and the app will think it's saying one thing when it's really doing something else.

Comment: Thank you for replying, but can you explain it more?
let me give you a scenario, suppose I created a login page flutter app
which is exported to web. (abc.com)
Now, this login page hits an api call at xyz.com (which is not accessible to owner of abc.com) to check if the user is licensed or not.

Can they by pass this check?
If yes, how?

Can you please explain? 
- thanks again!

Comment: If your app connects to xyz.com, then it has to be reachable from client side (mobile or web).  And a proxy between the client and the internet can rewrite xyz.com requests and responses to be anything.

Comment: Got it, you mean that we can still configure a proxy to change the response of xyz.com; maybe use burp suite to change the response in network layer, but not change the code right?